# WAMP Virtual Host Not Working with Personal Project

Tags: apache, wamp

I have virtual machine running windows 2012 server in a LAN that is connected to the internet. There is also a wamp server in the windows server.. I have configure a wamp virtual host in the machine with the following details

```
Apache version is 2.4.18
Mysql version is 5.7.11
PHP version is 5.6.19
```

The project folder is datacentre
This is the path.

```
C:\wamp\www\datacentre
```

When I type localhost into the url I get the wamp home page
when I type localhost/datacentre into the url I get the datacentre homepage
But when I type datacentre into the url it rather it serches the net.

this is the path to the host file

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

This is the host file from the windows server.

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#ne
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

   127.0.0.1 localhost
   127.0.0.1 datacentre

  ::1 localhost
  ::1 datacentre
```

This is the path for the httpd.conf file

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf
```

Uncommented the virtual host line.

```
    # Virtual hosts
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

this is the path to the httpd-vhost file

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra
```

This is the httpd-vhost.conf file

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName datacentre
     ServerAlias datacentre
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/datacentre"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/datacentre">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: There does not look like there is much wrong with that. You could take the spaces out of the HOSTS file before the IP address, other than that did you also reboot the server after making all these changes

Comment: Are you trying to access the site from the PC running WAMPServer or another PC on the network?

Comment: Please report last record line in `c:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log` into your question body through edit (dont use comments section). Also, did you restart Apache server (restart all services in WAMP on windows tray icon)?